# \color{} command behaviour

Tags: color, pdf

I noticed the `\color{declared-colour}` command changes even the black colour in my figure, which is imported from a separate PDF. It seems like this command replaces *every instance* of black with the chosen alternative at document creation time.

How does it do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a minimum working example, beginning with `\documentclass`.

Comment: Your separate PDF picture does not defined its own color and uses the current color...

Comment: I see. How can I verify this? Is there a way to decode and read the PDF source?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't normally do that.  Basically It has no "idea" what it is colouring it just pushes a colour change in to a stack in the back end (PDF, usually) graphic state and then arranges a stack pop to restore the colour at the end of the group. Most PDF files that you include  will be immune to this as they will set and restore the graphics state themselves but it's possible to have a simple PDF that just draws a line in whatever the current colour is.